# Can't see my system-drive - where is it?

Tags: partitioning

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my iMac. I created a partition with Bootcamp and instead of installing windows i installed ubuntu.

When installing Ubuntu i selected to install it additionally to Mac OS, not to overwrite.

It seems to have been working, but i can't find my ubuntu drive now?

I see Mac OS X - drive with all Mac OS data on it, i see "Bootcamp"-Drive, but its empty?

This is what `sudo fdisk -l` gives out, may be helpful for you.

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 243201 Zylinder, zusammen 3907029168 Sektoren
Einheiten = Sektoren von 1 × 512 = 512 Bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x558a880e

   Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1          39          19+  ee  GPT
/dev/sda2              40      409639      204800    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda3   *      409640  1951581479   975585920   af  HFS / HFS+
/dev/sda4      1951581480  1952851015      634768   af  HFS / HFS+

Platte /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 8579 MByte, 8579576320 Byte
255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 1043 Zylinder, zusammen 16756985 Sektoren
Einheiten = Sektoren von 1 × 512 = 512 Bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4d306ae6
```

Comment: mark CLOSED ...

Comment: This doesn't need to be closed, since I'm reverting it.

Answer (score 2):

Posted by @RD_RU:

> Problem solved - I didn't realise that i have to click at the "file system" (or however its called in english) - link.